# No afg or mfg node found and no codecs initialized

Tags: boot, sound, 22.04, intel, codecs

I'm stuck since yesterday at boot after the last updates in a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04, and I can't go to the desktop.

[image]

Comment: Same here, Ubuntu 22 is such a piece of crap. I had maybe a dozen issues with it since I installed it. Ppl. say that Ubuntu 21 is a lot more stable, maybe I'll reinstall the system and try that one when I have more free time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having the same issue after updating one of my Ubuntu 22.04 machines after an update on a Dell Optiplex 5090, the error message I get is identical. In my case, it is related to my device being out of storage space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting this message after computer was powered off without shutdown.
IT also gives the message hdaudio C1D0 not found.

Unable to get sound from external monitor. Connect through HDMI cable and in sound settings the only output device option is Digital output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio

[image: results of lspci -k]

Answer (score 1):

Me too. I use Sony TV as a second monitor. It was working as expected until a few days ago, when the HDMI option in sound output disappeared. On bootup I have the message "no AFG or WFG node found. No codecs initialized."